# Vertex Cache for animation

Tags: python

Environment:
Blender 3.4
Windows 10

I'm getting my hands on available Blender's vertex caching techniques.
There are two options: MDD or ABC(Alembic)
You can export/import data in both formats and two modifiers **Mesh Sequence** Cache for Alembic and **Mesh Cache** for MDD are available.

Data in .mdd format is imported/exported by using an add-on, which by default is disabled.
It's written in Python and applies data as shape keys, which I believe is not so optimize way to apply cache.
On the other hand, when I use the modifier Mesh Cache, I don't see any shape keys and it's fast which is obvious because in Blender modifiers are written in c/c++.

My question is, in what way modifiers are applying cache data to mesh? Are they creating per-frame GPU buffers or something like that? If one can access the same method in Python to apply cache data to mesh then I'm sure performance would be better in comparison of shape keys method.
If one cannot access the underlying technique of modifiers then what would the idle technique to apply cache data meshes to gain the best performance? Is it the shape key method used by MDD importer?